# force zypper to install a specific version

Tags: rpm, suse, zypper

I have my own personal repo with older versions of rpms in it. If I want to install boost-license version 1.36.0.11.17 I do the following

```
zypper install boost-license=1.36.0-11.17
```

this seems to be broken however as if I change the rev to one I know doesn't exist then it simply reverts to installing the latest rev instead of erroring, which is stupid.

I find the only way to force zypper to installa specific rpm I want is to state the exact rpms URL httlp//mylocalrepository/myrpms/boost-1.36.0.11.17.src.rpm.

Any ideas how I can use zypper as it was designed to install a specific version and error if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9):

```
zypper in -f <package-with-version>
```

If you want to find out exact version, you can find it with:

```
zypper se <package>
```

Comment: Can u give me an example?

Comment: Sure. Setting: I have qemu version 2.0.2-42.1 installed. I have older version in one of the repos, so: `zypper se -v qemu`, find my desired version, and then `zypper in -f qemu-2.0.0-40.7` This will do downgrade. Of course if you have no version installed, you simply choose which one you want. And you do not have to worry about update. Until you run `zypper dup`, it will not switch to different repo to gain higher version.

Comment: What does package-with-version mean?

Comment: `zypper se <package>` (at least now on openSUSE Leap 15, but I thinks it was already the same in 12.1) does not give version, but `zypper se -s <package>`  gives all available versions. Or maye you were meaning something else with "find out exact version" ?